# Way to map a relative path to an absolute one in a SystemJS loader environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, systemjs, commonjs

I am using SystemJS loader (with commonJS modules, but that shouldn't be important), mostly to directly access components under `node_modules`.

Now at runtime, is it possible to lookup the absolute path in the current environment from a relative one?

I.e. if I do `require('./myComponent')` it will fetch `http://localhost:3000/app/myComponent.js` but in case this component is installed via `npm install` (hence resides under `node_modules`) SystemJS will correctly load `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/dist/myComponent.js`. Is there a way to lookup this absolute path from a relative one?

I.e. something like `var absPath = SystemJS.lookup('./myComponent')`?

Answer (score 3):

It's called `normalize`, and it returns a promise that resolves to absolute URL,
as defined by the current SystemJS configuration:

```
SystemJS.normalize('./myComponent').then(function(url) {

});
```

Returning a promise means there is no guarantee that it will not perform any network loading - for example, if plugins or custom loaders are involved, it might need to load plugins first.

Also, it takes optional second argument - name of the parent module, because one can define package-specific mappings in the configuration.